# Git not picking up sub-command in path

Tags: git

I'm trying to add a git subcommand. I believe all that's required is to have an executable called `git-whatever` somewhere in my `PATH` and that will let me run it as `git whatever`. However it's not working for me.

```
[tamlyn ~/.bin] $ ls
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   4 tamlyn  staff       136 20 Oct 09:40 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 44 tamlyn  staff      1496 19 Oct 17:56 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 tamlyn  staff        19 20 Oct 09:40 git-test*
[tamlyn ~/.bin] $ cat git-test 
#!/bin/sh
echo OK!
[tamlyn ~/.bin] $ cd ..
[tamlyn ~] $ git-test
OK!
[tamlyn ~] $ git test
git: 'test' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    reset
```

I'm running git 2.5.3 installed via Homebrew on OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: What is the output from `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Does the path of _git-whatever_ show up when you run `which git-whatever`? If not, it's not in your path.